# Magento 2 add extra button in backend

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, magento2, overrides

I'd like to add another button in the backend on the cms page edit view. So I've created a module (with the help of: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-block-in-Magento-2/m-p/6831):

**app/code/Company/Modulename/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Company_Modulename" schema_version="0.0.1" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Cms" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Modulename/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit" type="Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Company/Modulename/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Edit.php**

```
<?php
namespace Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Page;

class Edit extends Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit {

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->buttonList->add('Test',[
            'label' => __('Test')
        ]);
    }
}
```

And added it to the **app/etc/config.php** file: `'Company_Modulename' => 1`

But this gives me an error:
`Fatal error: Class 'Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit' not found in C:\git-projects\magento2\app\code\Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit.php on line 4`

Do I need to reference to something else, because the **app/code/Magento/Cms/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Edit.php** file starts with:

```
namespace Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page;
class Edit extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
```

And is this the cleanest way to accomplish this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit {` is using the namespace you have declared `Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit` so becomes `Company\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit`

Your missing a \ from the front of the extended class so that it doesn't use the current namespace - you should then have

`class Edit extends \Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit {`

That fixes the error - but there may still be a better way to do this.

Comment: Just missed one backslash, thank you! Any suggestions to do this in a better way are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use [plugins](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) instead of declaring preference in your case. The main benefit is that there will be no conflicts if another extension will try to modify/extend the same functionality. Keep in mind that there can be only one active preference for each class/interface, priority is defined according to **sequence** in the final merged *module.xml*

Preferences should be used when there is a need to provide custom implementation of core interface.

Comment: That looks nice! I'll dig into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with a plugin on `\Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Page\Edit` using `beforeSetLayout` since there is in \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container this:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->toolbar->pushButtons($this, $this->buttonList);
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

In method `beforeSetLayout` use `$subject->addButton()`.